How to efficiently read/write from deltalake using Delta standalone?
I want to know is there a way to execute a point query in delta stand alone.
Reader Class
Snapshot latestSnapshot = deltaLog.update();
    StructType schema = latestSnapshot.getMetadata().getSchema();

    EqualTo filterCondition = new EqualTo(schema.column("id"), Literal.of(4));

    CloseableIterator<RowRecord> iter = latestSnapshot.open();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        RowRecord row = iter.next();
        Object obj = filterCondition.eval(row);
        if((Boolean)obj)
        {
            System.out.println(row.getInt("id"));
            System.out.println(row.getString("name"));
            System.out.println(row.getDouble("salary"));
        }
    }

This is not an efficient way to find any specific record.
I also tried like this:
DeltaScan scan1 = _latest.scan(filterCondition1);
    CloseableIterator<AddFile> iter2 = scan1.getFiles();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
        AddFile addFile = iter2.next();
        // Access the file
    }

In the above example, its iterating over all the files. This is also not an efficient way to query.
Please suggest , Is there any other way to efficiently query a specific data / point query?
Writer class:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Path to the Delta table
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    //S3 config...      
    
    Path basePath = new Path("D:/Work/POC/namespace");
    Path tablePath = new Path(basePath + "/employee");
    Path filePath = new Path(tablePath + "/data-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".parquet");

    DeltaLog deltaLog = DeltaLog.forTable(conf,tablePath);


    List<AddFile> deltaFiles = deltaLog.snapshot().getAllFiles();
    if (!deltaLog.snapshot().getAllFiles().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Delta table already exists.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Define schema for the Delta table
        StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add("id", new IntegerType())
                .add("name", new StringType())
                .add("salary", new DoubleType());
        System.out.println("Creating delta table...");
        Metadata metadata = Metadata.builder().schema(schema).build();

        Protocol protocol = new Protocol(1,2);
        deltaLog.startTransaction().commit(Collections.singletonList(metadata),new Operation(Operation.Name.WRITE),"Create Delta Table Schema");
    }


    writeDataToParquet(conf,filePath);
    addFileToDeltaTable(deltaLog,filePath.toString(),conf);


}

private static void writeDataToParquet(Configuration conf, Path filePath)
{

    MessageType schema = MessageSchemaTest.ParquetSchema.getEmployeeSchema();

    try (ParquetWriter<Group> writer = ExampleParquetWriter.builder(filePath)
            .withType(schema)
            .withConf(conf)
            .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
            .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
            .withRowGroupSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)
            .withPageSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
            .withDictionaryEncoding(false)
            .withValidation(false)
            .withWriterVersion(ParquetProperties.WriterVersion.PARQUET_1_0)
            .build())
    {

        SimpleGroupFactory groupFactory = new SimpleGroupFactory(schema);
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
        {
            writer.write(groupFactory.newGroup()
                    .append("id", i)
                    .append("name", "Employee_" + i)
                    .append("salary", 50000.0 + i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void addFileToDeltaTable(DeltaLog deltaLog, String filePath, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    // Get file size
    Path path = new Path(filePath);
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
    long fileSize = fs.getFileStatus(path).getLen();
    // Create AddFile action
    AddFile addFile = new AddFile(
            filePath, // Path to the Parquet file
            Collections.emptyMap(), // Partition values (if any)
            fileSize, // Size in bytes (will be updated later)
            System.currentTimeMillis(), // Modification time
            true, // Data change flag
            null, // Stats
            null // Partition values as JSON
    );

    // Start a new transaction and commit the AddFile action
    deltaLog.startTransaction().commit(Collections.singletonList(addFile), new Operation(Operation.Name.WRITE),"Adding data file");
}

Everytime, when i run this Writer class, it creates a new parquet and delta log file , since i'm creating a file with timestamp. I don't know if this the correct approach? Can i optimize the files and Z-order a column? I don't find much information about delta standalone apis.
I would like to know the efficient way of reading/writing the large scale of data.

The page you linked has a usage section and other sections like quickstart. You should at least describe what you have found and tried and what your issues were with them.
